# 'java.lang.NoSuchMethoderror in java application which uses ehcache for cache implementation

Tags: ehcache-2

I am facing below error when I run my java application which uses spring framework and ehcache for cache implementation. This application is build on IBM Integration Bus which Java and spring framework.

The full error stack is as below

```
+BIP2230E (Msg 2/4) MQJLMBRK ARCI511 147 ERROR DETECTED WHILST PROCESSI     
 NG A MESSAGE IN NODE 'ARFAL_MobilePortProtection01.FailureHandler.Tran     
 sform Failure'.                                                            
+BIP4367E (Msg 3/4) MQJLMBRK ARCI511 147 THE METHOD 'evaluate' IN JAVA      
 NODE 'FailureHandler.Transform Failure' HAS THROWN THE FOLLOWING EXCEP     
 TION: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/ehcache/jcache/JCacheManager.ge     
 tEhCacheNativeCacheManager()Lnet/sf/ehcache/CacheManager;.                 
+BIP4395E (Msg 4/4) MQJLMBRK ARCI511 147 JAVA EXCEPTION: 'java.lang.NoS     
 uchMethodError'; THROWN FROM CLASS NAME: 'com.anz.common.cache.impl.Lo     
 calCacheHandler', METHOD NAME: 'getCacheManager', FILE: 'LocalCacheHan     
 dler.java', LINE: '99'
```

---

The code where error has triggered is as below

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.anz.common.cache.impl;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheManager;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheException;
import net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService;

/**
 * ehCache Cache Handler in JCashe JSR107 standard API
 * Cache Handler Factory -> Cache Handler -> Caching Provider -> Cache Manager -> Cache
 * @author sanketsw
 * 
 */
public class LocalCacheHandler extends AbstractCacheHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static LocalCacheHandler _inst = null;



    public LocalCacheHandler() throws Exception {
        super();
    }

    /*public static LocalCacheHandler getInstance() throws Exception {
        if (_inst == null) {

                _inst = new LocalCacheHandler();
        }
        return _inst;
    }*/


    @Override
    public String getDefaultCacheName() {
        return "DefaultMap";
    }

    @Override
    public String getCachingProviderName() {
        return "org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheCachingProvider";
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.anz.common.cache.impl.AbstractCacheHandler#getCache(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Cache<String, String> getCache(String cacheName) throws CacheException, Exception {
        Cache<String, String> cache = null;

        try {

            //logger.debug("Retriving cache {}", cacheName);
            cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);   

        } catch(Exception e) {
            //logger.debug("Retriving cache using type classes {}", cacheName);
            try {
                cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName, String.class, String.class);
            }catch(Exception e2) {
                logger.throwing(e2);
            }
        }
        if (cache == null) {
            //logger.debug("Starting cache {}", cacheName);
            MutableConfiguration<String, String> jcacheConfig = new MutableConfiguration<String, String>();
            jcacheConfig.setTypes(String.class, String.class);          
            cache = cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, jcacheConfig);
        }
        return cache;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.anz.common.cache.impl.AbstractCacheHandler#getCacheManager()
     */
    @Override
    public javax.cache.CacheManager getCacheManager() throws Exception {
        javax.cache.CacheManager ret =  super.getCacheManager();

        try {
            // Register for JMX management
            JCacheManager ehCacheManager = (JCacheManager)ret;
            MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            ehCacheManager.getEhCacheNativeCacheManager().setName("LocalCacheManager");
            //logger.info("printing mBeanServer {}", mBeanServer);
            //logger.info("printing EhCacheNativeCacheManager {}", ehCacheManager.getEhCacheNativeCacheManager());
            ManagementService.registerMBeans(ehCacheManager.getEhCacheNativeCacheManager(), mBeanServer, true, true, true, true);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            //logger.info("net.sf.ehcache:type=CacheManager,name=LocalCacheManager is already registered for JMX management. Ignoring...");
            //logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCacheManagerURI() {
        String path =  System.getenv("CACHE_CONFIG");
        //logger.info("System property CACHE_CONFIG={}",path);
        File configFile = new File(path + "/" + "ehcache-localcache.xml");
        if(configFile.exists()) {
            try {
                return configFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                logger.throwing(e);
            }
        } else {
            URL resource = LocalCacheHandler.class.getResource("ehcache-localcache.xml");
            if(resource != null) {
                //logger.warn("Loading a backup config file={}",resource);
                return resource.toString();
            }
        }
        //logger.warn("Could not load the resource {}", "ehcache-localcache.xml");        
        return null;
    }







}
```

Any clue what could be the issue.

Comment: Do you have any code you could post?

Comment: Hi Stuart. Updated the code. Can you please have a look and let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Sorry @GirishK - I'm not a java dev - I was just reviewing the post.